# how to set id in jquery ui autocomplete source event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I wanted to use the auto complete widget to allow someone to select an employee by typing in an employee name into the text box, but I want the form to post the ID of the employee, not the employee name.I provided the data  ie the employee names as source. the label and value in the .js is same as the source i provided how can i possible to get employee name and id separate.

```
  $("#txtEmployeeName").autocomplete({  
                   var suggestions =  [] ; 
                   //define callback to format results  
                   source: function(req, add){  
                   ajax call...                 
                   on success: function( data ) 
                   {                   
                      suggestions = data.split('|');
                      add(suggestions);
                   } 
                   select: function(e, ui) { 
                     //create formatted friend  
                     var friend = ui.item.value,
                         span = $("<span>").text(friend)  
                         $("#"+ $(this).attr("id")).val(span);  
                    } 

                });
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to pass a json object to the source propertie.

Then your ui.item is the object, with Id, value, everything you want.

```
$(function() {                  
    var students = [{id: 1322,label: "student 1"},{id: 2,label: "Student 2"}];
    $( "#search-student" ).autocomplete({
        source: students,
        minLength: 2,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
              window.location.href="/?studentId=" + ui.item.id;
        }                   
    });             
});
```

Look at jQuery's getJSON : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ to get json via ajax.