# jQueryUI autocomplete with url as source (am using Django)

Tags: django, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using Django web-framework for database, page generation etc.

**jQueryUI / javascript side of the code**

I want to use [jQueryUI's autocomplete widget](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/), as my data set will contain about 1,000 entries I wanted to query the database. On the link above it claims you can simply provide a url that returns JSON data:

> Autocomplete can be customized to work
>   with various data sources, by just
>   specifying the source option. A data
>   source can be:
>
> ```
> * an Array with local data
> * a String, specifying a URL
> * a Callback
> ```

I have taken the [default example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#default) from the website, which works on my system.

However if I change the following:

```
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags,
    });
```

to

```
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: "/search/", // url that provides JSON data
    });
```

the autocomplete functionality doesn't work at all.

I've tried making the url actually return an error (to see if it uses it) and putting in the full url `http://localhost:8000/search/`, nothing works.

**Django part of the code**

In url.py

```
...
    (r'^search/$', 'search'),
...
```

In views.py

```
from django.http import HttpRequest, HttpResponse
from django.utils import simplejson 
...
def search(request):
    HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(["hello", "world"]))
    # Will implement proper suggestions when it works.
```

There must be something wrong with my code and I would greatly appreciate any help you can offer :)

**EDIT SOLUTION:**

Thanks to @Thierry realised it didn't have a `return` statement before, have added that so I now looks like so:

```
def search(request):
    output = ["hello", "world"]
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(output))
```

And it actually works!

(It always seems to be the really small bugs that waste the most of of my time, grrr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I return my ajax response like the following:

```
def search(request):
    output = ["hello", "world"]
    return HttpResponse(output, mimetype="application/javascript")
```

If you access the url `http://localhost:8000/search/`, you should see the output.  Once you see the output, the autocomplete should work.

Comment: Unfortunately when I go to the url I get the following error: ValueError at /search/
The view games.views.search didn't return an HttpResponse object.

Comment: Can you add the return statement in the search view like above, I've just added it.

Comment: Oops, fairly classic mistake, I should have spotted that. It now displays something when I visit the page http://localhost:8000/search/ But there is still no autocomplete on the input box. I suspect the problem lies within the way it calls view in the javascript.

Comment: Have added the return statement to my original code and it actually works now! Thank you so much, I've spent so long trying different things with this. Am very happy now :D

Answer (score 1):

There are some changes in json serialization API in later versions

- For django 1.6 use

  ```
  import json
  from django.http import HttpResponse
  ....
  return HttpResponse(json.dumps(my_data_dictionary))
  ```
- For django 1.7+ do it like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428092/creating-a-json-response-using-django-and-python/24411716#24411716)