# Retrieving data from html forms with php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html

I'm working on an assignment where I'm supposed to build a set of web forms so you can submit data to a database and add an entry to a specific table. I built a field that helps the user with suggestions retrieved from the db through a php request, basically while the user types into the field, a list of suggestions pops up and he/she can select an option.

Let's say I'm adding a new entry in a 'books' table and I can fill the 'author' form only with elements from the 'authors' table (so the user can't put an arbitrary author). To do that I used the autosuggestion method.

The 'books' table has a foreign key 'aut_id' which is the id attribute (primary key) of the 'authors' table.

As I said before I'm using php to retrieve the list of suggestions (author name, author surname and author id as well). But once the user clicks on a suggestion the web form is filled with the author name and surname and I don't know how to take advantage of this query so that when the user clicks "Submit" the aut_id field is properly filled.

I'll put some code, here is the HTML + Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function lookup(inputAuthor) {
        if(inputAuthor.length == 0) {
            // Hide the suggestion box.
            $('#suggestions').hide();
        } else {
            $.post("suggestionRetriever.php", {queryString: ""+inputAuthor+""}, function(data){
                if(data.length >0) {
                    $('#suggestions').show();
                    $('#autoSuggestionsList').html(data);
                }
            });
        }
    } // lookup

    function fill(thisValue) {
        $('#inputAuthor').val(thisValue);
        setTimeout("$('#suggestions').hide();", 200);
    }
</script>
```

...more hrml...

```
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputAuthor">Author</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAuthor" placeholder="Author name" onkeyup="lookup(this.value);" onblur="fill();">
    </div>

    <div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions" style="display: none;">
            <div class="suggestionList" id="autoSuggestionsList">
                &nbsp;
            </div>
    </div>
```

And here is the php I'm using to retrieve the suggestion list:

```
if(!$db) {
    echo 'ERROR: Could not connect to the database.';
} else {
    if(isset($_POST['queryString'])) {
        $queryString = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['queryString']);          
        if(strlen($queryString) >0) {

            $query = $db->query("SELECT aut_name, aut_surname, aut_id FROM author WHERE aut_name LIKE '$queryString%' LIMIT 10");
//I could echo the aut_id but I wouldn't know how to retrieve it on Submit with php
            if($query) {
                while ($result = $query ->fetch_object()) {
                    if(!$result->aut_surname){
                        echo '<li onClick="fill(\''.$result->aut_name.'\'); return false"><a href="">'.$result->aut_name.'</a></li>';
                    }else{
                        echo '<li onClick="fill(\''.$result->aut_name.' ' .$result->aut_surname.'\'); return false"><a href="">'.$result->aut_name.' ' .$result->aut_surname.'</a></li>';
                    }
                }
            } else {
                echo 'ERROR: There was a problem with the query.';
            }
        } else {
            // Dont do anything.
        }
    } else {
        echo 'There should be no direct access to this script!';
    }
}
```

The form is then filled with the proper name and surname but that's not what I need. So I can't use the $_POST php function as I do for any other field. I know I can solve this problem somehow, but I'd like to know the most proper way to do it. I'm kind of new to php so I might be missing something, I read some people using the DOM to retrieve the proper content. I could do another query to the db on submit so that it would look for the id of the author the user typed and then INSERT the proper data, but I think there might be a way to take advantage of the query I already did to retrieve the suggestions list. I just don't know how.

If I didn't make the problem clear enough please ask me anything and I'll try to do better. Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would return the aut_id in the php script such as

PHP:

```
if($query) {
                while ($result = $query ->fetch_object()) {
                    if(!$result->aut_surname){
                        echo '<li onClick="fill(\''.$result->aut_name.'\', \'' + $result->aut_id + '\''); return false"><a href="">'.$result->aut_name.'</a></li>';
                    }else{
                        echo '<li onClick="fill(\''.$result->aut_name.' ' .$result->aut_surname.'\', \'' + $result->aut_id + '\''); return false"><a href="">'.$result->aut_name.' ' .$result->aut_surname.'</a></li>';
                    }
                }
```

You could add a hidden field and then on the form which you would set the value of the hidden field in the `fill` function.

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputAuthor">Author</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAuthor" placeholder="Author name" onkeyup="lookup(this.value);" onblur="fill();">
        <input type="hidden" id="hiddenAutId"/>
    </div>

    <div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions" style="display: none;">
            <div class="suggestionList" id="autoSuggestionsList">
                &nbsp;
            </div>
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
function fill(thisValue, autId) {
        $('#inputAuthor').val(thisValue);
        $('#hiddenAutId').val(autId);
        setTimeout("$('#suggestions').hide();", 200);
    }
```

Also have a look at this question, if you return your authors in JSON format you can skip the hidden field.

[how to set id in jquery ui autocomplete source event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895748/how-to-set-id-in-jquery-ui-autocomplete-source-event)

Comment: Thank you! Worked lika a charm! I think I'm gonna stick with this but do you think is bad practice using a hidden field instead of the JSON format ?

Comment: It is entirely up to you. I would be sending the data via JSON in anycase but whether you populate the field itself or a hidden field is up to you.  In the linked answer (if it didn't redirect), once selected, the actual displayed `value` would become the id of the item which sometimes is not what you want to display to your users for obvious reasons so you would have to have a hidden field in anycase.